# session empty back button browser cache

Tags: php, session, browser-cache

I know this is a common question but can't seem to get this to work.

A user logs in and a session and a variable is added.

Then the user logs out and a php script is run and the session is destroyed.

I print out the session on the index.php page after logout and it is empty.

But the user can still see the login page if they press back???

I am using the following code to destroy the session:

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);
unset($_SESSION["username"]); 
header("Location: index.php");
```

using this to test if the session has been destroyed on the index.php page:

```
print_r("session".$_SESSION);
```

Each page also has this code to prevent caching:

```
 header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");    // Date in the past
 header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
 header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");  // HTTP/1.1
 header ("Pragma: no-cache");

 <meta http-equiv="expires" content="WED, 01 JUL 2009 05:00:00 GMT" />
 <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
 <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

I can successfully prevent the user from typing in the web address url and accessing the secure pages using the code below:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{ 
echo 'no session in here';

session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);
$_SESSION['username'] = '';
header("Location: index.php");
die("Redirecting to: index.php"); 
}
```

Comment: FYI, your last code block is wrong. You need to put the `header()` call before the `echo`. Best order is all of the `session_*` stuff, then `header`, then `echo`, then `die`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

session has to be start very first line of script

```
<?php session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{ 
echo 'no session in here';

session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);
$_SESSION['username'] = '';
header("Location: index.php");
die("Redirecting to: index.php"); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks its all sorted now.